# any way to combine background-size classes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change background-size using css: I want 100 heights and 100 widths, but do not want to create 10,000 classes. e.g.

```
// style
.tall {background-size: whatever 200%}
.narrow {background-size: 50% existing}
// javascript
element.className ="tall narrow";
```

As car as I can tell, I need to specify every possible value, e.g.

```
.tall1 {background-size: 1% 200%}
.tall2 {background-size: 2% 200%}
.tall3 {background-size: 3% 200%} // etc.
```

Is there any way round this?

Comment: if you are only on to CSS, i guess there is none. is JS an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Javascript, you could [dynamically set the values](http://javascript.gakaa.com/style-backgroundposition.aspx).

```
element.style.backgroundPosition = value1 + '% ' + value2 + '%';
```

Comment: Is this fast? I'm using CSS because it is so fast for animation. E.g. http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/ - I get the impression that using existing CSS is much faster than changing through javascript, or am I being dumb?

Comment: Changing the inline style like this should be very fast. By the looks of that article (if you're going for something similar), it's a choice between changing the class of the element many times in quick succession, or doing the same to the inline style. Either way, you're just changing a DOM element property (so they should be as fast as each other, at least).